# List of band names of image in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

What is the equivalent of the following syntax of Java in Python?
    [an_image.bandNames()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_info)

oh well, minimal example for minimal-example-seekers:

```
    DDD = [
           [-119.6407034633335, 46.24481372235483],
           [-119.6408917723115, 46.24488458019852],
           [-119.6410025340358, 46.24492625773868],
           [-119.6409025226398, 46.24509979439763],
           [-119.6403588110883, 46.24607095679298],
           [-119.6378330575554, 46.24505154496256],
           [-119.6378477085695, 46.24503421710987],
           [-119.6375762996203, 46.24492301512146],
           [-119.6378468749315, 46.24462749295479],
           [-119.6386649272333, 46.24406085261441], 
           [-119.6396165642001, 46.24437708363979], 
           [-119.6407034633335, 46.24481372235483]
    ]

    a_polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(DDD)

    start_date = '2018-03-1'
    end_date = '2018-10-30'

a_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filter( # searches all sentinel 2 imagery pixels...
                                                          ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 
                                                                       10)).filterDate( start_date,
                                                                                        end_date).filterBounds(a_polygon)
```

I want to see the bands in there. what I have tried? `a_collection.bandNames()`

did the minimal example and what I have tried make any difference? I do not think so.

simple question, equivalent of `bandNames()`? Either you know it, or you do not!

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Your question must be self-contained; the off-site link to critical information is not acceptable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API being used, but it looks like in your linked example, `bandNames` is a method on an `Image`, but in your example, you have an `ImageCollection` -- did you overlook this?

Comment: @Kevin Wang, I found the solution and posted it below. if you do `a_collection.getInfo()` you will get all the information. If there are 45 images in the imageCollection, you will get all of information. so, I did `a_collection.getInfo()['features'][0]['bands']` to get information of one image in the collection which is a representative of all images.


There might be better, simpler ways, like `.bandNames()` of java script, but I am not aware of it.
Than you

Comment: Note: please direct future Earth Engine questions to [GIS Stack Exchange (google-earth-engine tag)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) to help keep questions consolidated for easier discovery and engagement by the EE community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a_collection.getInfo()['features'][0]['bands']
```

or even better:

```
a_collection.first().bandNames().getInfo()
```

The following tutorial is also a useful source.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/csaybar/EEwPython

P.S. It is intentional to have the address attached to the hyperlink visible. As opposed to some thing like [CLICK HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/github/csaybar/EEwPython).

Answer (score 2):

> simple question, equivalent of `bandNames()`?

The equivalent of the JS

```
ee.Image(...).bandNames()
```

in Python is exactly the same:

```
ee.Image(...).bandNames()
```

You can see a large number of examples of this by searching for, e.g., "image.bandNames" on GitHub with a language filter for Python.